# Screen is rotated. How to adjust it?

Tags: graphics

When I installed the ubuntu 10.04 amd 64bit, the screen is shifted to left and cannot be fully showed on the monitor. I cannot even seclect the list on the top pannel. How should I adjust it?

Comment: you mean it´s rotated on a different direction?, are you using any propietary drivers? ATI/AMD or Nvidia?

Comment: @Uri..yes, it's rotated. how to get a driver?nvidia.

Comment: well ok if you´re not using a driver, click on the Additional drivers, under the System menu on the top panel.

Comment: Try changing your desktop resolutions.

Comment: you can change the rotation of the screen by going to the Monitor settings

Comment: he said the screen is shifted to the left in the question details, yet rotated in the title and comments. no one should answer this question until he asks a concrete question.

Answer (score 2):

To change your desktop rotation, open up Monitors settings, and you should see a window that looks like this.

[image]

From there you can change your rotation.